# Extending co-op / internship into part time

Tags: contracts, employer-relations, student

I’ve been interning at this company for over a year. I did a full-time semester with them last year, was offered to work part-time for the 8 months following, and am now currently doing a second full time semester.

However, we’re getting quite close to the end of my term, and no one’s really approached me to see if I can continue into part time until I graduate in Spring 2023. And recently I’ve been working on documenting my processes so they can be transitioned after I “go away for school”.

Should I ask if I can stay part-time into the next semester? Or maybe this is an indication that they don’t want me anymore? They’ve obviously offered me part time in the past, so it must have occurred to them this time as well, no?

Ive done work with many of the teams/depts and gotten nothing but good feedback. I learn fast, I meet deadlines, and I always deliver on anything that’s asked of me.

But I do definitely feel like there’s more I can do, and will admit that I am a bit shy and feel intimidated to put up my hand in larger meetings often. I’m a student and still feel a bit small in a room full people with years of experience/expertise.

I’ve seen similar threads asking for advice, but I feel my situation is a bit unique in that I’ve been told I’ve been doing everything right, for quite a while, up until now when there’s just silence.

So wanted to get your thoughts - should I see if there’s a chance I can continue part time? Or does this just seem like a graceful way for them to let me go without hurting my feelings? :(

Like I said I’m just starting out my career, I don’t really know how to read these things yet. Obviously there’s no harm in just asking, but with my track record of success and their track record of offering me part time, where did I go wrong?

I just want to know if it’s likely that I was actually just bad and just being told I was good until they got rid of me. Is that a thing or are companies usually open about letting workers know that it’s not working / can be worked on?

TLDR; been interning at company for over a year. Offered part time extensions in the past, but current contract about to end and haven’t been approached for another extension. Worth asking to stay? or am I just being quietly let go even though I’ve been enthusiastic about the work and told everything I’ve done has been great and a huge help.

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's an old turn of phrase:

"If you don't ask, you don't get"

But I would go a step further - assuming that you like working for the company, I would come up with a business case as to why they should keep you - what value you bring to the company, what successes you had and why it's in their best long-term interest to retain you after this semester (and possible after you graduate)

Going through the process of making the case will be beneficial to you, even if it doesn't result in what you want.

Comment: Great advice, thank you so much!! Do you think I should approach my direct manager with this case? I think there’s value I can add to another department as well if I’m no longer needed in my current one. Should it be HR? Small company < 50 employees.

Comment: In fact my last extension was sparked during a brief chat I had with our CEO. We haven’t talked much since, but he seemed like he really liked me and basically made the extension happen. Would it be rude to skip my direct manager and maybe send CEO a message?

Comment: Go direct to your manager in the first instance. Having a chance meeting with the CEO is one thing, deliberately bypassing your manager is another.

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR: If you want to continue, it can do no harm to ask.